# VirtualHost redirect loop after applying SSL from COMODO

Tags: html, apache, ssl, redirect

After I applied the configuration it loops until I get an "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

This is my VirtualHost configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName     my-domain.com
    ServerAlias    my-site.my-domain.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/my-site
    ErrorLog /home/my-site/logs/my-site/error.log
    CustomLog /home/my-site/logs/my-site/access.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://my-site.my-domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin     admin@my-domain.com
    ServerName     my-domain.com
    ServerAlias    my-site.my-domain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/my-site
    ErrorLog /home/my-site/logs/my-site/ssl/error.log
    CustomLog /home/my-site/logs/my-site/ssl/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /home/my-site/SSL/site_com_ar.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /home/my-site/SSL/HSSL-5dceb81ff3d10.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/my-site/SSL/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I track down this issue?

Comment: Something i tested out: If i take out the redirect section both: http and https work

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it just in case anyone needs it:
i've added or modified a ".htaccess" file in each subdomain's root directory with the following:

First be sure you've got "mod_rewrite" enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then reset apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now create or modify (in case it already exists) ".htaccess" in your subdomain root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        # Redirect to HTTPS
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps you too!

Comment: Forgot to say ive removed a line in my virtualhost .conf file "Redirect permanent / https://my-site.my-domain.com/"